# Java workaround for instanceof

Tags: java, processing

I am making a GUI with function blocks in Java/Processing.

I have a general class which has methods just to manage the X and Y coordinates.
All the blocks themselfs inherrit from the general class.

This allow me to make a single array list

```
ArrayList <FunctionBlock> blocks = new ArrayList() ;
```

I can add and remove function blocks at will.

The problem I am having is that I have to use instanceof. For instance.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++)          // loop through all blocks
    {
        FunctionBlock block = blocks.get(i) ;        // declare a local function block

        if(block instanceof AND)    {    AND    and =   (AND) block ;   and.draw() ; }  // Can I do it differently?
        if(block instanceof OR)     {     OR     or =    (OR) block ;    or.draw() ; }
        if(block instanceof SR)     {     SR     sr =    (SR) block ;    sr.draw() ; }
        if(block instanceof DELAY)  {  DELAY  delay = (DELAY) block ; delay.draw() ; }
        if(block instanceof NOT)    {    NOT    not =   (NOT) block ;   not.draw() ; }
    }
```

Each individual function block has a draw() method. For every new block I add, I need to update this list among others.

I would prefer to use something like this

```
   for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++)          // loop through all blocks
    {
        FunctionBlock block = blocks.get(i) ;        // declare a local function block

         block.draw() ;    // compiler error ==> The function draw() does not exist.
```

In a single for-loop I want to call the `draw()` methods of all sub classes without having to check what the object is.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Change `FunctionBlock` to declare a `draw()` method. This method might be `abstract`.

Comment: An alternative to adding a `draw()` method (e.g. if you didn't actually want to bake the drawing functionality into the `FunctionBlock`) is to employ the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is happening because the `FunctionBlock` has no method called `draw()`. Add this method to your class `FunctionBlock` class:

```
public abstract class FunctionBlock {
    /** Draws the block */
    public abstract void draw();
    ...
```

Then in your subclasses, add the `@Override` annotation to the implementations:

```
@Override
public void draw() {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could define an interface that contains the `draw` method and then have your `FunctionBlock` class implement it:

```
interface Drawable {
    /** Draws the block */
    void draw();
}

public abstract class FunctionBlock implements Drawable {
```

If not every `FunctionBlock` class defines a `draw()` method, then you can have the individual subclasses implement the interface instead.  If this is the case, you just have to change the type of `block` to `Drawable`

Comment: Yes. That's the solution. Just made your `FunctionBlock` classes abstract, that was missing.

Comment: Query, this works but what is the purpose of ```@Override```. I tried leaving it out just to discover that it is not making any visual change. Project runs with and without

Comment: Adding `@Override` is not required, but is considered good practice because it will result in a compiler error if the method does NOT override a super class or interface method. This typically happens later on when the code is being maintained and someone renames or removes the base class method. Without the `@Override`, you would get no indication in the subclass that anything had changed; your method would just never get called. With the `@Override`, you will get a compiler error so you know to fix it.